# Delete dupes but keep multiple

Tags: sql-server

Below is the sample data

[image]

I want output as below.

[image]

How to write a delete query in a way that above should be my o/p and rest of the data should be deleted.

Comment: Does your table has any ID ? I don't see one in screenshot.

Comment: Can you give sample data instead of images ?

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a code writing service. Additionally, please post your data as formatted text, instead of pictures.

Comment: CarrierName   FirstName  LastName   ID
ABCD           Frank      Zor       1
ABCD           Frank      Zor       1
UHC            Frank      Zor       1
UHC            Frank      Zor       1
AMG            Frank      Zor       1
AMG            Frank      Zor       1
UHC            Frank      Zor       1

Comment: Learn to use the [edit] button. Don't just post things in the comments.

Comment: @JamesZ: Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

`Table` is table name and `Table_ID` is your Primary key for this table.

```
 DELETE
    FROM Table
    WHERE Table_ID NOT IN
    (
    SELECT MIN(Table_ID)
    FROM Table 
    GROUP BY CarrierName, FirstName,LastName,ID)
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks Whencesoever.